# error on drop default database error

Tags: mysql

I created a database named "default" in MySQL, but I am not able to drop it through MySQL shell:

```
mysql> drop database default;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default' at line 1
```

Also, I am not able to grant to a particular user I created with this database

```
mysql> grant all on default.* to 'myuser'@'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default.* to 'myuser'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

What went wrong? Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop database `default`;
```

Should do the trick. Same for grant.
Thru it is better to avoid usage of reserved keywords for naming your schemas/tables/columns etc.

Answer (score 1):

`default` is a reserved keyword used for assigning default values to fields:

```
create table t (a int default 1);
```

avoid using reserved keywords as table names, but if you want to do so you should enclose the word in `` ` ``s:

```
 drop database `default`;
```